# Where are AnyVal subtypes stored in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Java, within a method when we create primitives they are stored in stack memory, while objects instantiated (like using `new`) are put on heap. In scala, `AnyVal`’s subtypes(like `Int`) are immutable value instances that can’t be instantiated. So if I create an `Int` in a Scala method, does it go to heap or stack. I am asking it because in Scala `Int` is an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) does not say anything about how memory is organized. Every implementation is free to organize its memory however it wants.

By the way, your statements about Java are wrong:

> In Java, within a method when we create primitives they are stored in stack memory,

There is nothing in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/) which says that. And in fact, for many implementations, this isn't true. For example, Oracle JDK's implementation will try to store primitives in registers, or elide them completely, instead of storing them on the stack.

> while objects instantiated (like using 'new') are put on heap.

Again, there is nothing in the Java Language Specification which says that. And again, for example in Oracle's implementation, this is not necessarily true. Oracle's optimizing compilers will perform Escape Analysis and allocate objects on the stack whenever possible, i.e. when the compiler can prove that the reference doesn't escape the scope. [Azul's implementation](https://azul.com/products/zing/) always allocates objects on the stack (unless it can prove that the reference will definitely escape the local scope), and performs Escape Detection, i.e. when it detects a reference escaping the local scope, it will move the object from the stack to the heap.

In fact, you can implement Java without a stack at all, and be perfectly compliant with the Java Language Specification.

> In scala, AnyVal’s subtypes(like Int) are immutable value instances that can’t be instantiated. So if I create an Int in a Scala method, does it go to heap or stack.

That depends on the implementation, the version, the specific circumstances, and many other things. The Scala Language Specification doesn't say one way or the other, in fact, it doesn't say *anything* about how to memory, let alone about stack and heap.

> I am asking it because in Scala Int is an object.

But again, that doesn't say anything about how it is implemented. Scala-JVM, for example, implements `scala.Int` as a JVM primitive, and then simply "fakes" the methods.

Comment: "you can implement Java without a stack at all" - wait, what? Did you mean that you don't have to implement it as a *stack machine*? Because it still should have some kind of *call stack* somewhere, shouldn't it? I think even Scala language spec should say enough about `return`-statements and exception handling to imply that there actually should be some kind of stack. I'm not sure if it could be implemented as... I don't know... pure term rewriting system, without simulating some kind of stack implicitly?

Comment: My point is: there doesn't have to be a separate stack memory. You could, for example, allocate space for the stack on the heap. You could implement the stack as a dynamic linked list of stack frames, dynamically allocated on the heap. You could forego the idea of a call stack at all, and use dynamically allocated "soup" of continuations on the heap. I don't think any of those would be incompatible with either the JLS or the SLS.

Comment: Ok, yes, if it's specifically about the physical separation of the memory used by the stack and the heap, then those two don't have to be physically separated. The implementation can indeed do whatever it wants, e.g. a simple toy implementation can choose to represent both as some heap-objects in the host language that implements the jvm.

Comment: So physically we may not have heap-stack separation, but allocation of heap-stack memory still holds true..right?